# Bindings not set for items not visible

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, datacontext

Sorry if this is a dumb question.  I am maintaining this crazy Windows Phone 8.1 RT dynamic app that I didn't write.  It loads up a whole bunch of stuff to the DataContext.  Things that aren't visible on the screen don't seem to get their DataContext.  When I navigate away from the form the event fires.  What do I need to do to fix that?  Even when it scrolls into view it doesn't load.  If I scoll up and click the back button I see the field populate before it goes to the previous page.

Edit - Here is some code:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="com.somecompany.BarcodeboxRenderer">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding Item1}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource labelstyle}" Grid.Row="0" />
                <somecompany:BarcodeBox IsReadOnly="{Binding DisplayOnly}" somecompany:DynamicDataBindingPath.BindingPath="{Binding FieldId}" Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

That calls this but only if it's visible:

    public sealed class DynamicDataBindingPath:FrameworkElement
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingPathProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindingPath", typeof(string), typeof(DynamicDataBindingPath), new PropertyMetadata("", OnBindingPathPropertyChanged));

        public static string GetBindingPath(FrameworkElement target)
        {
            try
            {
                return (string)target.GetValue(BindingPathProperty);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public static void SetBindingPath(FrameworkElement target, string value)
        {
            target.SetValue(BindingPathProperty, value);
            target.Loaded += Target_Loaded;
        }

        private static void Target_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var target = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        if (target is ...) { ... }
        else if (target is DatePicker)
        {
            int startingletterindex = value.IndexOf('.') + 1;
            string pathtobindto = "obj." + Char.ToUpper(value[startingletterindex]) + value.Substring((startingletterindex + 1));
            Binding newbind = new Binding();
            newbind.Path = new PropertyPath(pathtobindto);
            var contextsrc = findRealDataContext(target);
            newbind.Source = contextsrc.DataContext;
            newbind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            (target as DatePicker).SetBinding(DatePicker.DateProperty, newbind);
        }
        else if (...)
     }
```

Comment: The code you have supplied is inadequate to answer your question.

Comment: The quick answer to your question's title is that items that are not visible do have their constructors called and do have their datacontext properties set. The most apparent issue I see might be the {binding Item1} part of DataContext, since an item in a repeater has its datacontext property set automatically by the framework.

Comment: That Target_Loaded(...) event isn't getting called if the control isn't visible. If I scroll up so I can see the control then press the back button the data populates and I can see it for a second before it goes to the previous page.

Comment: I added some code to show what it does when the Target_Loaded(...) event is called.  It sets the binding right there.

Comment: Okay, it's subscribing to FrameworkElement.Loaded but it's not firing when the control scrolls into view for the first time.

Comment: The controls are added to a ListView.

Comment: It's using itemtemplates.  When you scroll down the list the controls are there but the data is not.

Answer (score 0):

I turned of ListView Virtualization and it works now.  I don't need it because there will never be more than a handful of rows.